# How to group by when there is a column with unique data (SQL Server)

Tags: json, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2016

I am trying to group a selection of rows together that have a unique column in SQL Server.

Currently all the data is being selected as a standard 2-dimensional table that is being sorted is Javascript, however, it is very slow for large lists since the JSON is quite large.

I am hoping to improve front-end performance by transforming the dataset on the server side so the DOM renders more quickly.

I think this is achievable with some combination of SQLs `group by` function and possibly incorporating some of the newer functions like `openjson` in the newer versions of SQL Server.

**Example Table**

```
| a | b | c | uniqueColumn  |
|---|---|---|---------------|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | string1       |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | string2       |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | string3       |
```

**Example Select**

```
select
uniqueColumn
group by 
a,
b,
c
```

**Desired Output**

```
| uniqueSelection1 | uniqueSelection2 |
|------------------|------------------|
| string1          | string3          |
| string2          |                  |
```

How can I group each unique combination `a-b-c` into its own set when part of the dataset is unique?

Comment: This question is not very clear. Your sample query is invalid because you are grouping by only 3 of the 4 columns being returned and the 4th column is not an aggregate. But the desired output is where there is no clarity at all. Please provide a [mcve] so others can help you.

Comment: @SeanLange That's the issue that I'm running into. I'm thinking maybe I could do a while loop and select the aggregated tables at the end?

Comment: Does this mean, that you want to generate a JSON output?

Comment: @Zhorov The JSON are just unique strings. I had them listed as JSON to help explain why I'd want to do this. Let me update the question...

Comment: How do you want that last column formatted as an aggregate? Comma separated values? a JSON output? Please share your desired results as an actual SQL result set (rows and columns). That bit of JSON you put at the end doesn't show the first three columns as part of the output so it's entirely unclear how that is supposed to foot with your SELECT statement. Your "desired results" should contain the same sample data as in your sample table so we can see what went where.

Comment: `group by` is used for aggregation, but this is not an aggregation problem. Your language is a little challenged but it appears likely this is a partitioning or possibly even an algorithmic problem.

Comment: Furthermore what does "split each unique a-b-c selection into their own tables" mean? What does "join them to a master table" mean? There a lot of terms being used here that don't have any definition.

Comment: @JNevill I'd like to aggregate based on the uniqueness of `a,b,c` but return only the `uniqueColumn`s. I have updated the question.

Comment: Sounds like you need a dynamic pivot or dynamic crosstab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output in your desired results above with N number of columns, where `N` is the number of unique `a,b,c` values is going to be tough. Your processing on the application side may be faster than what it will take to write and execute a dynamic pivot like that on the SQL Server side.

---

Instead, if you have a newer SQL Server perhaps using the `FOR JSON AUTO` functionality may help even though it's not exactly like your desired output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
        SELECT uniqueColumn
        FROM yourtable
        WHERE a = t.a
            AND b = t.b
            AND c = t.c
        FOR JSON AUTO
        ) AS e
FROM yourtable t;
```

As an example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a int, b int, c int, d varchar(30));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,2,3,'string1');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,2,3,'string2');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4,5,6,'string3');
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT d FROM test WHERE a=t.a AND b=t.b AND c=t.c FOR JSON AUTO) as e FROM test t;

+-----------------------------------+
|                 e                 |
+-----------------------------------+
| [{"d":"string1"},{"d":"string2"}] |
| [{"d":"string3"}]                 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ef5b/7)

---

If you want to bring through the unique `a,b,c` selection that led to this output you could do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c, 
(SELECT d FROM test WHERE a=t.a AND b=t.b AND c=t.c FOR JSON AUTO) as e 
FROM test t
FOR JSON AUTO;

[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"e":[{"d":"string1"},{"d":"string2"}]},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6,"e":[{"d":"string3"}]}]
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ef5b/11)

Or to have a mixed result of table and json:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c, 
(SELECT d FROM test WHERE a=t.a AND b=t.b AND c=t.c 
FOR JSON AUTO) as e 
FROM test t;


+---+---+---+-----------------------------------+
| a | b | c |                 e                 |
+---+---+---+-----------------------------------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | [{"d":"string1"},{"d":"string2"}] |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | [{"d":"string3"}]                 |
+---+---+---+-----------------------------------+
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ef5b/13)

---

You can also use `FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` if you want to free those `d` outputs from the json array. Your output on this last query would be

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"e":"{\"d\":\"string1\"},{\"d\":\"string2\"}"},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6,"e":"{\"d\":\"string3\"}"}]
```

---

*Quick explain on what is happening:*

Essentially, with this subquery for `d` column (your uniqueString) we are doing something like:

```
SELECT a,b,c,AGGREGATE_IN_JSON(d) FROM yourtable GORUP BY a,b,c;
```

It's just that the syntax requires us to do that `AGGREGATE_IN_JSON` made up formula inside a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function to concatenate those jsons into one column. STUFF, probably, but if you have a newer version of sql server it could be STRING_AGG. Check out the example below

```
SELECT a, b, c, STUFF((SELECT N', ' + s.[CITY] FROM yourTable s 
             WHERE s.a = st.a
             AND   s.b = st.b
             AND   s.c = st.c
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')
FROM yourTable st
GROUP BY a, b, c
```